# Wordpress - Google fonts not working / importing correctly

Tags: php, css, wordpress, html

I'm quite new to Wordpress and I'm importing my stylesheets across using the html5blank theme. I've noticed the google fonts aren't applying in the wordpress site.

I have this link in my header.php file -

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather+Sans:100,200,400,700,700i,800,800i' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
```

And in my style.css file I have this -

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather+Sans:100,200,400,700,700i,800,800i');

body {
    font-family: "Merriweather Sans", sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #333333;
}
```

Do 'body' rules apply in Wordpress in the same way they would in a front-end situation? Or is there something else I need to add/change?

Comment: What do your developer tools show? Are your rules even being loaded? If they are, are they being overridden by other rules?

Comment: @j08691 Yeah, looks like they're being overridden but not sure why - I deleted all the styles and replaced it with my own. Is there something in the function.php that could be doing this?

Comment: If there are other CSS rules that are more specific than yours, your rules will lose out to those. If the specificity is the same, but the other rules are loaded last, then yours will lose out again.

Comment: @j08691 Many thanks. How do I find/rearrange the specificity ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you telling wp to load the stlye.css file?

Try doing this to your **functions.php** file:

```
function load_styles() {
  wp_enqueue_style('styles', 'path/to/style.css');
}
```

followed by (if your styles are for the site's **front-end**):

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_styles');
```

or (if your styles are for the site's **admin panel**):

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_styles');
```

Also, you're adding the fonts twice by doing:

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather+Sans:100,200,400,700,700i,800,800i' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
```

in your header and:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather+Sans:100,200,400,700,700i,800,800i');
```

in your style.css

Choose either one of those, **or you can add it to the "load_styles()" function in your functions.php file**:

```
function load_styles() {
  wp_enqueue_style('styles', 'path/to/style.css');
  wp_enqueue_style('fonts', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather+Sans:100,200,400,700,700i,800,800i');
}
```

If this doesn't work, please provide more information such as:

- Are there errors on your browser's developer console?
- Are the css rules showing up in the dev console?
- Are the fonts being loaded?

Comment: I've checked the developer tools and I think the theme has some rules which appear to be overriding mine. If i add this code to the function.php will this fix it? Also, whereabouts in the functions file do I put this code - with the other style functions?

Comment: I've checked again and there's a 404 server error relating to my style.css sheet - is this because I haven't applied the code above in the functions file?

Comment: @Mike.Whitehead The 404 error seems like an error in the url you've typed in as the path to the file.
I would look around the functions.php lines for the place where the styles are loaded (looking for the wp_enque_style or wp_enque_script), then I would set the styles I want to overcome the others as the last ones to be loaded.

Comment: This is the link to the stylesheet in my header.php file - <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory')?>style.css" /> Is this wrong? I'm not entirely sure what path I should be putting as they all just appear to be listed in the themes editor.

Comment: @Mike.Whitehead I think the output of bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') is 'path/to/your/theme/css' (you can check that by using your browser's code inspector) and if your style is in the root directory of the theme then it won't work, if that's the case use get_template_directory_uri() instead, also you need to add '/' to the style.css that comes after: somenthing like this: href="<?php get_template_directory_uri() ?>/style.css"

Comment: Many thanks. To be honest, this is all a bit confusing - some of my styles are working and some aren't. So, some are being overridden and some aren't but if some are working then surely the link to my stylesheet must be correct?

Comment: @Mike.Whitehead If you are seeing your styles being applied and getting a 404 error on the same stylesheet then my guess would be that you're trying to load it more than once.