# Google font not rendering in WordPress site

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts, webfonts, google-webfonts

I'm working with in WordPress and Google Fonts isn't rendering aside from on my Macbook (Chrome and Firefox).

I'm using the @import method for Archivo Narrow. Sample code is below:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Archivo+Narrow:400,400i,700');

h1 {font-family: 'Archivo Narrow', sans-serif; font-size:48px; color:#012233; font-weight:bold;}
```

Website in question is the following: eptestdev.us/northpage

Comment: did you clear cache?

Comment: Yes. Checked on multiple computers and multiple browsers.

Comment: Are the other styles from the same style-sheet rendering?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wordpress - Google fonts not working / importing correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45147936/wordpress-google-fonts-not-working-importing-correctly)

Comment: @crffty Yes, the other styles are rendering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding the font via your theme’s functions.php

```
function wpb_add_google_fonts() {
   wp_enqueue_style( 'wpb-google-fonts', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Archivo+Narrow:400,400i,700', false ); 
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpb_add_google_fonts' );
```

[wpbeginner.com how-add-google-web-fonts-wordpress-themes](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-add-google-web-fonts-wordpress-themes/)